# TDCH: not able to use SplitByHash method

Tags: hadoop, hive, teradata

I'm trying to perform an extraction from Teradata via TDCH to Hadoop.

I see an anomaly that even if I specify the `--method` to be any string (`hash, partition, amp, value`), it automatically takes in `SplitByPartition` value during extraction.

The table I'm extracting from Teradata is partitioned & I'm importing directly to hive table. I tried extracting even a single partition but couldn't change the automatic method selection.

I could very well go on with this approach but the problem is: 
during extraction, TDCH creates an intermediate query to extract the data from Teradata table & stores temporarily in a stage table. Then the transfer starts to Hadoop server from this temporary stage table. This query created is skewed 100% and thereby it fails the job every time due to low spool in the DB. The spool space is quite high (10 TB).

Thoughts?

Comment: sqoop works good, I'm using it with TD without issues.

Comment: sqoop has many limitations with TD that TDCH doesn't. Very slow as well over the network.